# Add a rule after chapter title using titlesec

Tags: sectioning, rules, titlesec

I've been experimenting with chapter title formatting using `titlesec` but I can't seem to find the proper way to add a rule just below the chapter title. After reading the doc, I found that `\titleline` does that, but I'm not sure where in the `\titleformat` syntax to place it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using the last optional argument for `\titleformat` to insert some vertical spacing and the rule:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\end{document}
```