# Rule after small caps subsection

Tags: formatting, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I know that this question has been answered before for section and chapter titles, but I cannot seem to apply it to subsection titles. I would like to globally change the format of subsection titles to the one presented in the MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  

\newcommand\ruleafter{\vspace*{-.5cm}\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\vspace*{-.2cm}}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\subsection{\textsc{Subsection title}}\ruleafter

\end{document}
```

I have tried using `titlesec`, but without success. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

PS: The questions considering the section and the chapter format, respectively:

[How can I make a bold horizontal rule under each section title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84061/how-can-i-make-a-bold-horizontal-rule-under-each-section-title)

[Add a rule after chapter title using titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69330/add-a-rule-after-chapter-title-using-titlesec)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you add links to the answers for section and chapter titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using `titlesec` then:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\scshape\bfseries} % format
  {\thesection}% label
  {1pt}% sep
  {\hspace{1ex}} % before-code
  [\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}]

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Subsection title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But now the text is not boldface anymore, and adding the option removes small caps, in turn.

Comment: The command `\sc`, along with all similar two letter commands, has been obsolete for 25 years.

Comment: @YulanvanOppen Sorry, forgot the bold face. The second mandatory argument to `\titleformat` is the formatting of the title. I updated the answer.

Comment: @egreg Indeed, I didn't realize until he asked for bold too. Thanks! `\scshape` and `\bfseries` are okay to use?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, these are good. On the other hand, not many font familes provide boldface small caps.

Comment: @egreg But this is not solvable at the LaTeX programming level, am I correct? The person who chose the font should be aware of that, right?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, that's right.